# Find a basis for a space of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $X = \lbrace x_1, x_2, . . .,x_n \rbrace$. Find a basis for the space $\mbox{Map}(X,\mathbb R)$.

Note: $Map(X,R)$ is the space of all functions that goes from $X$ to $\mathbb R$.

Note 2: I was thinking, one basis for that space can be 
$(1,0,...,0), (0,1,...,0) ,...,(0,...,1)$?

Comment: I don't understand, you are trying to find a basis for which vector space?

Comment: Yes, i trying to find a basis for the space.

Comment: For which one? The space of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: yes...! thanks for you interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, it is made up of the functions $f_i$ defined by
\begin{align*}
f_i\colon X &\longrightarrow \mathbf R\\
x_i&\longmapsto 1\\
x_j&\longmapsto 0\quad(j\ne i).
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, thanks for clear out

Comment: sorry, then that would be a basis for space (1,0,...,0) + (0,1,...,0) + (0,...,1) ??

Comment: @LilianaXArangurenX $(1,0,...,0)+...+(0,...,1)$ is not a space, it is just a vector (the sum of all those vectors). $\lbrace  (1,\ldots ,0), \ldots, (0, \ldots ,1)\rbrace$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ but you are asking for a basis of the space of all functions from a finite set $X$ to the reals, so the elements of your basis must be functions, the one given by Bernard is the canonical one. You can check that it generates any functions of your space and it is LI.

Comment: Writing $(1,0,\dots,0)$ and the like is just a way to denote these  functions with the list of their values, in the same order as the elements of $X$.

Comment: Thanks Eliana and Bernard!